# REST jersey json NoSuchFieldError: WADL and IllegalStateException

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, glassfish, tomcat7

I'm trying to build a WebApplication with REST Web Services and successfully fought some troubles already. But i couldn't solve this one so far.

I'm using a TomCat v7.0 localhost and try to access a simple @GET Resource. But when i click on the Resource, the following Errors appear:

```
A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor
```

I was searching stackoverflow and found a question with a maybe identical problem, but no solution (asked in April 2016)

I started this project as Maven project in eclipse neon.

Here are some files:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.project.projecttest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>data.controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecttest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projecttest</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>projecttest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**simple REST Test class:**

```
package data.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class RESTTest {

    @GET
    public Response getString() {
        return Response.status(200).entity("getString is called").build();
    }
}
```

**and finally the stack trace:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception


type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception  
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause  A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are: 
1. java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor

org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:394)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2151)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:245)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:457)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:310)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL    org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1104)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2151)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:245)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:457)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:310)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**my Libs:**
[referenced libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmL7K.png)
[WEB-INF lib-folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg8Yj.png)

I think the problem might be caused by some libs, but I'm not sure and several changes didnt fix this problem.

I'm thankful for each answer. If i forgot something, feel free to ask.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ IDE, Search for WadlModelProcessor class, you will see which library has this class. In this case, it will be more than one library.

You need to exclude one of the library which is the culprit from your pom.

In my case, it was jaxrs-ri - 2.11 jar - I excluded this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have miss the @RequestMapping annotation

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/methodName", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response getString() {
        return Response.status(200).entity("getString is called").build();
    }
```

Comment: Hello vaibhav patil, i've tried that, but with no success. even a easier way of the resource with "@GET()
 public String getString() {
  return "hello";
 }" like the maven example gives, didnt work.